# Handling Timezone Conversion in PHP 5.1

Tags: php, timezone

My server is running PHP 5.1, so I cannot make use of the DateTime and DateTimeZone functions.  I was trying to figure out how to do timezone conversions for such an old version of PHP, but since it's so old, I'm having trouble finding good resources for this.  Currently I have the following code, but I'm not sure if date_default_time_set() changes PHP's config settings, and therefore would affect all scripts running at the same time..?  I want it to defaultly be in UTC time, hence the last `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`  Please let me know if there are other, better ways to do this.

```
$toTimezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
$time = time();
date_default_timezone_set($toTimezone);
$time = date($format, $time);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Edit:  Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to upgrade the server this website will be hosted on.

Comment: Please upgrade or change server..

Comment: That is not an option.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set(); would only set the time zone for the time functions in that particular script and not change the settings in the php.ini file

Comment: setlocale? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: @CD001 Locale !== timezone.

Comment: And I thought I had it rough with my lonely 5.2 server I need to handhold... ;)

Comment: Re upgrade not an option: Please be aware that PHP 5.1 has several known and serious security holes. It is completely insecure, and you can be compromised simply by having it on a production server accessible from the web. You currently need to be on at least 5.3.28; anything lower and you are vulnerable to being hacked. Any sys admin who allows software with that kind of issue to remain on his network is being negligent, and the same applies to any manager who doesn't allow upgrades to happen.

Comment: @deceze good point ... hit return whilst I was thinking it through ... was trying to ponder whether you could do it by posting a value from a form through and juggling the locale ... thinking about it, yeah ... no :)

Comment: @Spudley  Oh, I'm definitely with you on that point.  *sigh*

Comment: The example you give is no-saying. You're overwriting the `$time` variable, you don't share what you intend to do here, what expected would be, what you're looking for instead etc. pp.